# Как в POST запрос добавить дату?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, дата, requests

```
import requests
payload ={}
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
           }
r =requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload, headers=headers)
print (r.text)




 {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "192.168.0.1", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: Дата у вас это data или date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправка данных POST запросом в типе `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Когда браузер отправляет данные из тега `<form>`, то в таком типе он и описывает их.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'a': '1',
    'date': str(datetime.now()),
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
}

rs = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", data=data, headers=headers)
print(rs.text)
```

---

Чтобы отправить данные в типе `application/json`, нужно вместо параметра `data=`, указывать `json=`: `rs = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", json=data, headers=headers)`

Модуль `requests` сам заполнит нужные заголовки